How to grant file manager access to my apps internal storage in android?
So I want a button that allows users to access a folder of my apps internal storage (/data/data/com.example.myapplication/files/savedFiles).
savedFiles contains subdirectories and audiofiles; the former should also be accessible, the latter replayable. I try to do it via FileProvider.
In MainActivity.kt:
filesButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            val context = applicationContext
            val file = File(getMyFilesDirectory(context).toString())
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", file);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
            intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

In AndroidManifest.xml:
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>

And finally, provider_paths.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>

What I was expecting: Click button -> get taken to savedFiles directory in my phone's file manager app and be able to access all files and subdirectories there.
What currently happens: The file manager for my phone opens and displays "can't use this folder. To protect your privay, choose another folder."
How can I fix that? I found some confusing stuff online, such as this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256669329 thread. I'm glad about any pointers, and sorry if it's a dumb/beginner's mistake! I searched around for over a day now

my apps internal storage (files/savedFiles) You better name full paths as then we only know where you are talking about.

OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is to let the user select a directory.

FileProvider is to serve one file.

Anyhow file managers and file explorers have no access to app private files from getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir.

thanks already! so the full path is /data/data/com.example.myapplication/files/savedFiles.
if I understand correctly, the current approach will not work in principle, right? Could you point me to a different approach, instead of FileProvider/OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?
Should I try to save to external storage instead?

If you save to public external storage ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is usable. But never FileProvider.
